# React-Loadable SSR with Webpack 4 and Babel 7

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4, react-loadable

Does server-side rendering with `react-loadable` work with Webpack 4 and Babel 7? I've been unable to get it working successfully while following [the instructions](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/blob/master/README.md).

After following just the client-side steps, Webpack correctly outputs separate chunks for each loadable component and this is reflected when I load the page in the browser (ie: the chunks are lazy-loaded).

After following all the SSR steps, however, the server throws the following error:

```
Error: Not supported
at loader (/Projects/test-project/web/routes/index.js:50:15)
at load (/Projects/test-project/web/node_modules/react-loadable/lib/index.js:28:17)
at init (/Projects/test-project/web/node_modules/react-loadable/lib/index.js:121:13)
at flushInitializers (/Projects/test-project//web/node_modules/react-loadable/lib/index.js:310:19)
at /Projects/test-project/web/node_modules/react-loadable/lib/index.js:322:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.Loadable.preloadAll (/Projects/test-project/web/node_modules/react-loadable/lib/index.js:321:10)
at Object.preloadAll (/Projects/test-project/web/server.js:15:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Module._compile (/Projects/test-project/web/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
```

My `routes/index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

import Loading from '../components/Loading';

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Loadable({
      loader: () => import('./controllers/IndexController'),
      loading: Loading,
    }),
    exact: true,
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    component: Loadable({
      loader: () => import('./controllers/HomeController'),
      loading: Loading,
    }),
    exact: true,
  },
  ...
];
```

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508714/using-react-loadable-with-nodemon) on SO is possibly related to the server error I'm seeing above, but provided even less info.

My `.babelrc` is already using `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`, but I tried adding [`babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node`](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node). This fixes the server issue but Webpack then no longer builds the chunks.

I've been unable to find a definitive example to get this working. There is conflicting info out there about proper setup. For example, the react-loadable README says to use the included `react-loadable/babel` plugin, while [this post](https://jamie.build/react-loadable-4.html) by the lib author says to use `babel-plugin-import-inspector`. [This PR](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/pull/110) seemed to be attempting to address Webpack 4 issues but was closed, and the forked lib appeared to have issues as well.

I am using:

- Babel 7
- Node 10.4
- React 16.5
- React-Loadable 5.5
- Webpack 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem today. After adding `dynamic-import-node` to the plugins of my `.babelrc` the server worked, but webpack wasn't creating the chunks. I then removed it again from my `.babelrc` and moved it to my server script with `@babel/register`. My server script now looks like this:

```
require( "@babel/register" )({
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    plugins: ["dynamic-import-node"]
});
require( "./src/server" );
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: I tried switching to Loadable Components but ran into similar issues. This solution worked! I'm a bit surprised more people haven't run into this issue using that library, but maybe there's something unique about my config.